# PHP uploading images using filepath in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms, pdo

I am trying to create a script that enter details from a book. The image variable 'image' and 'content' is supposed to be a jpg or PDF.  These are selected in the HTML create form of type 'file'.

I've been looking online at other peoples code as I am really struggling to get my head around it.

Heres what I have so far:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME,  DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $authors = $_POST["authors"];
        $description = $_POST["description"];
        $price = $_POST["price"];
        $image = $_POST["image"];
        $content = $_POST["content"];
        $uploadDir = 'path/to/where/i/can/save/';

            if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;


$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
if (!$result) {
echo "Error uploading file";
exit;
}

            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
$filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO books (title, authors, description, price, image, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$title', '$authors', '$description', '$price', '$filepath', '$content')");
$stmt->execute();
        }
```

Not surprisingly this does not do anything, the database remains empty and the page i'm presented with has nothing on it. Can anyone help me sort this out and also tell me how I could make it so that the content is also saved as a filepath.

Sidenote:

In the database i used VARCHAR to store the variables.

Comment: Does your HTML form tag have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? If not, try to putting it as the file uploads won't work without this.

Comment: Yes it does but good suggestion.

Comment: On that note, is the name of your file field "image"? Seems to be exiting the code.

Comment: Yes the file name is image.

Comment: Does your form contain a field named "submit"? What type of field is it?

Comment: its type is submit:  <input type="submit" value="create"/>

Comment: Exactly what I thought. Add `name="submit"` to it.

Comment: Thanks, it still not fixed the main issue though.

Comment: Is the screen still blank? Or do you see anything now?